# unable to compile googletest in eclipse

Tags: c++, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to compile googletest (git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git -b release-1.11.0) but keep getting 1000+ linker errors.

I am running windows 10, eclipse CDT (latest), mingw (latest) gcc. I created an eclipse c++ project (executable, empty project).

added include paths to:

- googletest
- googletest/includes
- googlemock
- googlemock/includes

added source location to:

- googletest/src
- googlemock/src

All is compiled without problems, but linking fails with 1000+ errors. Eg.

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
googletest\gtest.o: in function `testing::IsNotSubstring(char const*, char const*, wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*)':
C:\dev\unode\eclipse\unit_tests\Debug/../../googletest/googletest/src/gtest.cc:1821: multiple definition of `testing::IsNotSubstring(char const*, char const*, wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*)';
googletest\gtest-all.o:C:/dev/unode/eclipse/googletest/googletest/src/gtest.cc:1821: first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
googletest\gtest.o: in function `testing::IsSubstring(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
C:\dev\unode\eclipse\unit_tests\Debug/../../googletest/googletest/src/gtest.cc:1827: multiple definition of `testing::IsSubstring(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)';
googletest\gtest-all.o:C:/dev/unode/eclipse/googletest/googletest/src/gtest.cc:1827: first defined here
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
googletest\gtest.o: in function `testing::IsNotSubstring(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
```

I am reading googletests readme.md to figure out what I am doing wrong but getting nowhere. Some help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, there is a file
googletest/src/gtest-all.cc

which includes all source files. so all source files are compiled twice, deleting this file solves my problem